# Filtering rows between two dates in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a sheet which has Date, Sales and Profits. The data is for a history of 10 years. Now, i want to filter the sales between Jan1 and Feb 9 of each year. How can i do it?

Comment: What does your data look like? Is is it already in a datetype format? Can you share some existing code for us to see?

Answer (score 3):

First you want to make sure that your `Date` is datetime type:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then you can extract the months and days and filter with loc:

```
month_day = df['Date'].dt.month * 100 + df['Date'].dt.day

df.loc[month_day.between(101, 209)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Less simple than Quang Hoangs method, but maybe more readable/understandable:

```
df[(df['Date'].dt.month == 1) | ((df['Date'].dt.month == 2) & (df['Date'].dt.day <= 9))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `dayofyear` attribute of the [DateTimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html#pandas-datetimeindex) object:

Given Date is dtype datetime,

```
df[df['Date'].dt.dayofyear < 41]
```

To get the first 40 days of each year, 31 days in January plus 9 days in February.

If Date is in the index, then you don't need the dt accessor:

```
df[df.index.dayofyear < 41]
```